# SonarCloud quality check doesn't work after running scan

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, sonarcloud

I am trying to run sonarcloud-quality-gate check after performing sonarcloud-scan. I am doing this because I want bitbucket build pipeline should fail if the quality gate check is failed.

Doing this I get some error like this
Quality Gate failed: Could not get scanner report: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan/sonarcloud-scan.log'

This is how my bitbucket.yml looks.

```
image: node:10.15.3

clone:
  depth: full              # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

definitions:
  caches:
    sonar: ~/.sonar/cache  # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build

  steps:
  - step: &build-test-sonarcloud
      name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
      caches:
        - node
        - sonar
      script:
        - npm install --quiet
        - npm run test:coverage  
        - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:0.1.5
          variables:
            SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
            EXTRA_ARGS: '-Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.tests=src -Dsonar.test.inclusions="**.test.jsx" -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info'
        - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.1
          variables:
            SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-test-sonarcloud
```

Although solarcloud-scan pipe runs successfully.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate` pipe requires a newer version of the `sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan` pipe. (This was the case ever since the first release of the `sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate` pipe.)

Change your pipeline configuration like this:

```
    - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.0.1
      variables:
        SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
        EXTRA_ARGS: '-Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.tests=src -Dsonar.test.inclusions="**.test.jsx" -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info'
    - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.3
      variables:
        SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

An easy way to see the latest versions is in the pipeline editor.
When you edit the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file, a sidebar like this opens,
where you can filter the list by entering "sonar":

[image: pipes sidebar]

And then, click on a pipe to see details, and note the version used.